# How to create list of posts from the same category in django

Tags: django, django-views

I try to create list of posts from the same category in post detail. Something like related posts.

I try to do it this way:

Views:

```
subject = get_object_or_404(Subject, slug=slug)
subject_board_ids = subject.board.values_list('id', flat=True)
related_subjects = Subject.objects.filter(board__in=subject_board_ids).exclude(id=subject.id)
```

Model:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Tytuł')
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique=True)
    body = HTMLField(blank=True, verbose_name='Treść')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='subject', null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='subjects', verbose_name='Kategoria')
    votes = GenericRelation(LikeDislike, related_query_name='subjectsvotes')
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Actual result is error: 'Board' object has no attribute 'values_list'.

I try to create max 6 related posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you have error, because your Subject link on Board with using FK. And you expression **subject.board** give you 'Board' object not 'Board' Queryset. To get related subject just use:

```
subject = get_object_or_404(Subject, slug=slug)
related_subjects = Subject.objects.filter(board=subject.board).exclude(id=subject.id)
```